# How can I compare complex strings in python?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I scraped a site that has Turkish months and wrote code to convert it to Gregorian months;
but it doesn't work.
How can I compare complex strings like this?

```
if month=="Kasım":
    #tested
    #return "November"
    return 11
if month=="Aralık":
    #tested
    return 12
    #return "December"
if month=="Ekim":
    return 10
    #return "October"
if month=="Eylül":
    return 9
    #return "September"
if month=="Ağustos":
    return 8
    #return "August"
if month=="Temmuz":
    return 7
    #return "July"
if month=="haziran":
    return 6
    #return "June"
if month=="mayıs":
    return 5
    #return "May"
if month=="nisan":
    return 4
    #return "April"
if month=="mart":
    return 3
    #return "March"
if month=="şubat":
    return 2
    #return "February"
if month=="Ocak":
    return 1
    #return "January"
```

I copied the string from the scraped site but my converter always returns the result of the first `if` in the function; for example: it always returns 11.
Is there another way to compare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you make it a dictionary you can just access it as such.

```
turkish_months = {
    "Kasım": 11, # "November"
    "Aralık": 12, # "December"
    "Ekim": 10, # "October"
    "Eylül": 9, # "September"
    "Ağustos": 8, # August"
    "Temmuz": 7, # "July"
    "haziran": 6, # "June"
    "mayıs": 5, # "May"
    "nisan": 4, # "April"
    "mart": 3, # "March"
    "şubat": 2, # "February"
    "Ocak": 1 # "January"
}
```

Then to access it:

```
current_month = "Ekim"
turkish_months[current_month]
```

If your code is always returning 11: I suspect the problem is not with your conversion but instead with the data you are trying to convert.  You are more than likely trying to convert the same piece of data again and again but thinking that it is not the same.  Try printing the data going into your converter before you try to convert it so you can be sure it is working properly, then remove the prints after.